# Can I do this with a custom Visual Studio Code Extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to have an additional feature in Visual Studio Code - essentially the "Scope to This" from the full Visual Studio Solution Explorer.

It is basically a context menu (right click) entry in the File Explorer of Visual Studio Code - which then should limit which files and folders are displayed.

Is such a thing possible with a Visual Studio Code Extension?

I never built an extension for VS Code before and would like to know if this is even possible or if I would just waste my time.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the API docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api), there is no way to filter visible files in the Explorer like it can usually be done with the `files.exclude` setting. However, [it is possible](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api-commands) to open another folder with the `workspace.openFolder` complex command. This will probably also close all opened editors, and forget about the original workspace root path.

Your extension would need to remember the initial root path and opened editors to undo this "Scope to This" menu, and reopening everything every time could cause quite some lag.

Answer (score 0):

You can't customize the normal explorer view.

However, you can do something like this with [custom views](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_13#_extension-authoring). It allows you to create a *new* explorer view that can list what you want and behave as you want.

For an example implementation, check the [vscode-code-outline](https://github.com/patrys/vscode-code-outline).

If you can add a context menu entry separately too.